# Can I load Python scripts as Glib GModules?

Tags: python, c, gnome, glib, vala

I have a Linux application written in C (actually Vala which compiles to C) that loads modules via Glib's [GModule 2.0](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html) API. I'm interested in writing a module for it in Python. **Is that possible?**

Python has GModule bindings via GObject-introspection (PyGI) and I've found documentation for them [here](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/GModule_2.0/index.html) but that looks like that's functions for loading modules and not for being loaded as a module.

According to [this blog post](http://blog.eikke.com/index.php/ikke/2005/05/18/gmodules_are_fun), in C the loaded module uses `G_MODULE_EXPORT` to export its functions to the core and the docs I found don't seem to list anything like that.

Comment: Well, python is designed to be embedded. You can almost certainly do what you want by creating a GModule which embeds the python interpreter, and then loads a python script. In fact, there's a fair chance someone has already done that; google for it.

Comment: Well, there's https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2009-September/msg00024.html which doesn't really clear anything up as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  It would be quite painful to do it directly via GModule, and explanations of everything you would need to do are way beyond a stack overflow answer.  Luckily someone has already done the work: [libpeas](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libpeas).